# Patch cannot proceeed one specific diff

Tags: python, diff, patch

I have got one specific file like this:

```
 +
 +                        %3)+Lorem
 +
 +                        %4)+Lorem
 +
 +                        %5)+Lorem
 +
 +
```

I generate unified diff using python 2.7 difflib with all context lines:

```
--- bug-3.txt   2012-07-23 15:25:42
+++ FILE    2012-07-23 15:25:42
@@ -1,8 +1,10 @@
 +
 +                        %3)+Lorem
 +
 +                        %4)+Lorem
 +
 +                        %5)+Lorem
 +
++                        %6)+Lorem
++
 +
```

And when I call patch (patch --verbose bug-3.txt bug-3.patch) it gives me this error:

```
Hmm...  Looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- bug-3.txt  2012-07-23 15:25:42
|+++ FILE   2012-07-23 15:25:42
--------------------------
Patching file bug-3.txt using Plan A...
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file bug-3.txt.rej
done
```

I thing there could be bug in patch. Do you have any idea what exactly cause this error and what to do with it?

I run Ubuntu 12.04 and patch patch 2.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the original file contains a single space at the beginning of each line, but that space is missing from the diff.  I would expect your diff output to look something like this:

```
--- bug-3.txt   2012-07-23 15:25:42
+++ FILE    2012-07-23 15:25:42
@@ -1,8 +1,10 @@
  +
  +                        %3)+Lorem
  +
  +                        %4)+Lorem
  +
  +                        %5)+Lorem
  +
+ +                        %6)+Lorem
+ +
  +
```

Perhaps you are calling `strip()` on each line from the file before generating the diff?

Comment: You are right. I have got a little bit more complex file and this is only change. I entered original file wrong, it should by without leading space on each line. But my example works, so problem is somewere else in my file. Thank you.

Comment: I found solution for my problem. Patch is little fit sensitive on right number of new lines on ned of .patch file.